# Как получить поле "Наблюдатели" у задачи в youtrack js workflow?

Tags: youtrack

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно получить Наблюдателей у задачи?

Пробовал по-разному:

```
1) issue.fields.Watchers
2) issue.watchers
3) issue.fields["Наблюдатели"]
```

Эти варианты не работают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]